# java - Remove nearly duplicates from a List

Tags: java, duplicates, levenshtein-distance, concurrentmodification

I have a List of Tweet objects (homegrown class) and I want to remove ***NEARLY*** duplicates based on their text, using the Levenshtein distance. I have already removed the identical duplicates by hashing the tweets' texts but now I want to remove texts that are identical but have **up to 2-3 different characters**. Since this is a O(n^2) approach, I have to check every single tweet text with all the others available. Here's my code so far:

```
int distance;
for(Tweet tweet : this.tweets) {
     distance = 0;
     Iterator<Tweet> iter = this.tweets.iterator();
     while(iter.hasNext()) {
         Tweet currentTweet = iter.next();
         distance = Levenshtein.distance(tweet.getText(), currentTweet.getText());
         if(distance < 3 && (tweet.getID() != currentTweet.getID())) {
             iter.remove();
         }
     }
}
```

The first problem is that the code throws ConcurrentModificationException at some point and never completes. The second one: can I do anything better than this double loop? The list of tweets contains nearly 400.000 tweets so we're talking about 160 billion iterations!

Comment: "_have already removed the identical duplicates by hashing the tweets' texts_". What now? `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` **does not imply** `a.equals(b) == true`! Only the opposite implication is true. And this must be true of **any** hashing, as the variable space for the hash must be smaller than the variable space of the original value (or you could just use _it_ as the hash).

Comment: You're removing objects from the list you're looping over in the outer for-each. That's not allowed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I was not using the hashCode() function for the tweet objects but for the texts. So, tweets by different people that have identical tweet texts were removed. Actually, from 1M tweets initially, now I have 390K.

Comment: Indeed, and as I said this **does not work**. Having the same hashcode implies that two strings **might be** equal. There are as many as `10^800` possible tweets but only `2^32` possible values for an `int`. Chances are that you removed many non-duplicates.

Comment: copy data from one list to other list using distinct() methods using lambdas

Comment: @BoristheSpider: you are right, I haven't considered that. Even if I don't use the hashCode() method, hashing a String in a HashMap<String, Tweet>, would result in using hashCode() internally?

Comment: @PiXel1225 `HashMap` uses both `hashCode` **and** `equals`. Simplistically, it uses `hashCode` to narrow down whether two things _could_ be equal, only then does it use `equals` to check whether they are.

Comment: code looks like List<String> = dataListuWantToCopy.stream().distinct(),collect(collectors.toList);

Comment: @BoristheSpider so, there's no appropriate way to remove duplicate tweets using hashing, am I getting that right?

Comment: @Akhil I'll use that, thanks!

Comment: look at my commen i provided the code to do so

Comment: @PiXel1225 what do you mean? If you were to dump your tweets into a `HashMap<String, Collection<Tweet>>` keyed by the tweet's text, you would group all tweets by their message - with the same ones ending up mapped to the same key. The point is that `HashMap` uses **both** `hashCode` **and** `equals`. You cannot determine equivalence on `hashCode` alone.

Comment: cheers bro im not good at whers to caps and small logic is correct but im not sure of syntaxes please go through net

Comment: @Akhil I don't see how that helps at all. What you have demonstrated is how to get all the unique **tweets** not the tweets with a **unique message**.

Comment: It is new feature in java8 where distinct() is used to remove all duplicates values and remaining code to copy list elements to other list i guess now its good to understand the code

Comment: @Akhil yes, and as I said, it determines distinct elements using `equals` (via a `HashSet`). The OP wants to find all tweets **with the same message** and **not** all **identical tweets**. These two are not the same thing at all.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm using a HashMap<String, Tweet> not a HashMap<String, Collection<Tweet>>. Every time a tweet with the same text arrives, I choose to ignore it, because the hashmap already contains a key with the same text.
But I understand what you're saying. Hashing can't be used for the purpose I want, because hashcode alone cannot determine equivalence. I'll stick with the Levenshtein, Could we get back to my original question, please?

Comment: Can you use HashSet and override equals and hashCode in Tweet class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**As for the *ConcurrentModificationException*:** As the others pointed out, I was removing elements from a list that I was also iterating in the outer for-each. Changing the for-each into a normal for resolved the problem.

**As for the `O(n^2)` approach:** There's no "better" algorithm regarding its complexity, than a `O(n^2)` approach. What I'm trying to do is an "all-to-all" comparison to find nearly duplicate elements. Of course there are optimizations to lower the total capacity of `n`, parallelization to concurrently parse sub-lists of the original list, but the complexity is quadratic at all times.

Comment: "_Changing the for-each into a normal for resolved the problem_". This doesn't solve anything, it just _masks_ the problem. The reason the list throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` is because removing elements during iteration **must** be done via an `Iterator` - otherwise you risk running over the end of the `List` in the best case. In the worst case, you silently skip and element during iteration. Pro tip: heed errors, don't mask them.

Answer (score -1):

---

This solution works for the question in hand(so far tested with possible inputs) but the normal set operations to remove duplicates wont work if you dont implement the full contract for compare to return 1,0 and -1.

---

Why dont you implement your own compare operation using the Set which can have only distinct values. It is going to be O(n log(n)).

```
Set set = new TreeSet(new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Tweet first, Tweet second) {
                int distance = Levenshtein.distance(first.getText(), second.getText());
                if(distance < 3){
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }
        });
        set.addAll(this.tweets);
        this.tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>(set);
```

Comment: "_It is going to be O(n^2) like your code_". Wrong. `add` on a `TreeSet` is `O(lg n)`, doing that `n` times will be `O(n lg n)` - **much** less `O(n^2)`... But your `compareTo` method doesn't work as if `a.compareTo(b) > c` then `b.compareTo(a)` **must be** `-c`. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). This means that the behaviour of the `TreeSet` is **undefined** with the comparator.

Comment: Yes it is O(n log(n)). I'll update the answer. But the compareTo will just work fine for the problem in hand.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab No. It will not. Because you are relying on a property of `TreeSet` - that no two elements will be allowed for which `a.compareTo(b) == 0`. This property cannot be guaranteed if you do not fulfil the contract of `compareTo` - you do not define a total order. So this answer is wrong, and encourages the terrible practice of invoking undefined behaviour and assuming it's fine because there is no exception.

Comment: Bad practice I get it, but issue with the solution I dont get it. Can you give me a piece of code which will fail for the problem in hand.

Comment: This is also clearly documented in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html. *For example, suppose one adds two elements a and b such that (a.equals(b) && c.compare(a, b) != 0) to an empty TreeSet with comparator c. The second add operation will return true (and the size of the tree set will increase) because a and b are not equivalent from the tree set's perspective, even though this is contrary to the specification of the Set.add method.*

Comment: That is **not** what is clearly documented there. That is "_consisten[cy] with equals_". What you have violated here is an **explicit requirement** not a recommendation - "_The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`_". So you have violated an explicit interface contract requirement. This behaviour of `TreeSet` is undefined and implementation dependant. It might work (very unlikely), it might seem to work but have "strange issues" (very likely), or it might just randomly blow up.

Comment: For example, see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/29966b35d2679e7a0157) - `a` is in there twice, `b` is in there twice. This is simply a consequence of implementation specifics and insertion order. The outcome could potentially be _anything_. This answer is **dangerously** wrong. I would strongly recommend you tell the OP and delete it to avoid spreading misinformation.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to fix it with compare contract with the Ideone example and see.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have tested your example code and found that you are totally correct. I deleted all my previous comments and unmarked this answer as correct. Could you please send me a link with the operation of the insertion in TreeSet? I still don't get why the compare() method violates this procedure.

Comment: Finally, I understand that there is no possible way of finding nearly duplicates using the Levenshtein distance if not for a O(n^2) algorithm, right?

Comment: @PiXel1225 a `TreeSet/Map` in Java is implemented as a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). The reason the `compare` method doesn't work it because it doesn't provide a [**total order**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) - it's an `equals` method disguised as a `compare` method. To work, it **must** be the case that `a.compareTo(b) == -b.compareTo(a)` - this obviously isn't the case.

Comment: @PiXel1225 as to your second question - I don't think so, no. As you need to compare each pair of elements, which must be `O(n^2)`. I don't think you can speed this up with hashing, as I can't see of a way to produce a meaningful hashcode in the context of `Levenshtein` distance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for your answer!